# Write a PL/pgSQL function so that FOUND is not set when "nothing" is found?

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I am just starting out on functions in PostgreSQL, and this is probably pretty basic, but how is this done?

I would like to be able to use the following in a function:

```
PERFORM id_exists();
IF FOUND THEN
   -- Do something
END IF;
```

where the `id_exists()` function (to be used with SELECT and PERFORM) is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION id_exists() RETURNS int AS $$
DECLARE
  my_id int;
BEGIN
  SELECT id INTO my_id
  FROM tablename LIMIT 1;
  RETURN my_id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Currently, even when `my_id` does not exist in the table, `FOUND` is true, presumably because a row is still being returned (a null integer)? How can this be re-written so that an integer is returned if found, otherwise nothing at all is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, `FOUND` is set to `TRUE` if the last statement returned a row, regardless of the value (may be `NULL` in your case). Details in the manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS).

Rewrite to, for instance:

```
IF id_exists() IS NOT NULL THEN
   -- Do something
END IF;
```

**Or** rewrite the return value of your function with **`SETOF`** so it can return multiple rows - **or no row**! Use `RETURN QUERY` like I demonstrate. You can use this function in your original setting.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION id_exists()
  RETURNS SETOF int LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY
  SELECT id
  FROM   tablename
  LIMIT  1;
END;
$BODY$;
```

**Or**, even simpler with a **language SQL** function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION id_exists()
  RETURNS SETOF int LANGUAGE sql AS
$BODY$
  SELECT id
  FROM   tablename
  LIMIT  1;
$BODY$;
```